# How to change output text in datacursor mode for a plot with double y-axis with single x-axis

Tags: matlab, image-processing, plot, handles

I have the following code:

```
datee = {'23-10-201511:36:24', '23-10-201511:37:24', '23-10-201511:38:24', '23-10-201511:39:24', '23-10-201511:40:24', '23-10-201511:41:24', '23-10-201511:42:24', '23-10-201511:43:24', '23-10-201511:44:24', '23-10-201511:45:24'};
Temperature = [23.6, 23.6, 23.7, 23.7, 23.7, 23.7, 23.7, 23.7, 23.7, 23.7];
Humidity = [40, 40, 40, 39.9, 39.8, 39.7, 39.8, 39.8, 39.8, 39.8];
C = datenum(datee,'dd-mm-yyyyHH:MM:SS'); 
[ax,h1,h2] = plotyy(C,Temperature,C,Humidity)
hold on;
datestr(C); 
datetick(ax(1),'x','HH:MM','keepticks');
datetick(ax(2),'x','HH:MM','keepticks');
xlabel('time [hours]');
ylabel(ax(1),'Temperature [°C]');
ylabel(ax(2),'Humidity [%rH]');



dcm_obj = datacursormode(gcf); 
set(dcm_obj,'UpdateFcn',@myfunction);

function [output_txt] = myfunction(~,event_obj)
% Display the position of the data cursor
% obj          Currently not used (empty)
% event_obj    Handle to event object
% output_txt   Data cursor text string (string or cell array of strings).


pos = get(event_obj,'Position');


output_txt= {['time: ', datestr(pos(1))],...                           
    ['Temperature: ',num2str(pos(2),4)]};

 output_txt= {['time: ', datestr(pos(1))],...                           
    ['Humidity: ',num2str(pos(2),4)]};

If there is a Z-coordinate in the position, display it as well
if length(pos) > 2
output_txt{end+1} = ['Z: ',num2str(pos(3),4)];
end
```

If I use this code, I see only `time` and `temperature` variables for both the y axes but not the humidity variable.

I would like to see something like if I click on one y-axis it must display `time` and `temperature` and for other y axis, `time` and `humidity`.

Comment: please include some example data, so we can execute your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, you want to have different data tips based on which line is clicked on. One method to accomplish this is to compare the `Target` of your `event_obj` to the handles of your line objects returned by `plotyy`:

```
function testcode
datee = {'23-10-201511:36:24', '23-10-201511:37:24', '23-10-201511:38:24', '23-10-201511:39:24', '23-10-201511:40:24', '23-10-201511:41:24', '23-10-201511:42:24', '23-10-201511:43:24', '23-10-201511:44:24', '23-10-201511:45:24'};
Temperature = [23.6, 23.6, 23.7, 23.7, 23.7, 23.7, 23.7, 23.7, 23.7, 23.7];
Humidity = [40, 40, 40, 39.9, 39.8, 39.7, 39.8, 39.8, 39.8, 39.8];
C = datenum(datee,'dd-mm-yyyyHH:MM:SS');
[ax,h1,h2] = plotyy(C,Temperature,C,Humidity);
hold on;
datestr(C);
datetick(ax(1),'x','HH:MM','keepticks');
datetick(ax(2),'x','HH:MM','keepticks');
xlabel('time [hours]');
ylabel(ax(1),'Temperature [°C]');
ylabel(ax(2),'Humidity [%rH]');


dcm_obj = datacursormode(gcf);
set(dcm_obj,'UpdateFcn',{@myfunction, [h1, h2]});
end

function [output_txt] = myfunction(~,event_obj, linehandles)
% Display the position of the data cursor
% obj          Currently not used (empty)
% event_obj    Handle to event object
% output_txt   Data cursor text string (string or cell array of strings).

pos = get(event_obj,'Position');
targetline = get(event_obj, 'Target');

switch targetline
    case linehandles(1)
        output_txt = {['Time: ', datestr(pos(1))], ...
            ['Temperature: ',num2str(pos(2),4)] ...
            };
    case linehandles(2)
        output_txt = {['Time: ', datestr(pos(1))], ...
            ['Humidity: ',num2str(pos(2),4)] ...
            };
    otherwise
        % No match
        output_txt = {['X: ', datestr(pos(1))], ...
            ['Y: ',num2str(pos(2),4)] ...
            };
end

% If there is a Z-coordinate in the position, display it as well
if length(pos) > 2
    output_txt{end+1} = ['Z: ',num2str(pos(3),4)];
end
end
```

Two main changes here: I have passed `h1` and `h2` to your callback for use with the [`case-switch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/switch.html) statement I added. You can use an equivalent [`if-else`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/if.html) statement but I personally find `case-switch` more elegant.

And the corresponding datatips:

[image: yay]
[image: yay2]